# How to disable new user email activation in JHipster ?

Tags: jhipster

On new user registration, 
I tried setting

```
    private boolean activated = true;
```

but that did not help.

How to disable new user email activation in JHipster ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit `UserService.createUser()` and change these lines:

```
    // new user is not active
    newUser.setActivated(false);
    // new user gets registration key
    newUser.setActivationKey(RandomUtil.generateActivationKey());
```

to what is done in `activateRegistration()`:

```
    // activate given user
    newUser.setActivated(true);
    newUser.setActivationKey(null);
```

and of course, delete the line sending the activation email:

```
   mailService.sendActivationEmail(user);
```

Comment: On JHipster 7, the first block of the above code is now located in `UserService.registerUser()`

Answer (score 0):

the same can be achieved by inserting

```
    // auto-activate newUser
    this.activateRegistration(newUser.getActivationKey());
```

before

```
    return newUser;
```

into `UserService.createUser()`.

Of course `registerAccount()` in `AccountResource` has still to be changed:

```
// see UserService.java => auto-activate newUser
// mailService.sendActivationEmail(user);
```